# Why does my CATextLayer not respond to the contentsGravity property?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I am creating a Cocoa app with a `layer-backed NSView`. I have customised the layer backing the view to be of type `CATextlayer` because the primary purpose of this view is to display some text.

I include the following line in my `init` procedure and it does not work for any of the contentsGravity constants that I have tried:

```
textLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityBottomRight
```

On the other hand, the following does take effect:

```
textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentRight
```

So basic horizontal alignment is working but I can't adjust in vertical space.

**What is the best way to specify the positioning of the text in the `CATextLayer`?** I have also been trying to modify the `NSParagraphStyle` attribute in the backing attributed string but this also doesn't seem able to position the text?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

===

Note: the CATextLayer is *not* a subLayer of the layer backing my `NSView`. It *is* the type of layer backing my view. I have achieved this by overriding makeBackingLayer() in my custom `NSView` as follows:

```
override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
  return CATextLayer()
}
```

I include that in case it is somehow relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can think of the text you set for your `CATextLayer` as the *content* of this layer, this doesn't make it the  the value residing in the `contents` property of that layer. In fact I'm pretty sure that the `contents` property of a `CALayer` can only be an image (or nil). If the value is `nil` the values you set for `contentsGravity`, `contentsRect` and `contentsCenter` - all of which operate on this `contents` property - will do nothing.

My guess is that the `contents` property of your text layer is nil (and will remain nil regardless of what text value you set), and this is why nothing is happening.

Comment: Interestingly contentsRect does have an effect on the text in the layer. I have checked with a quick println() though & the contents are indeed nil. What then is the best way to go about positioning this text in your view then?